# remove blank space before image

Tags: spacing, graphics

When I insert a figure, there is some blank space before it that Latex adds it. How do I remove it?

```
\headerbox{Poster Box 1}{name=box1,column=1, below=box2}{
  \begin{minipage}{20em}
    \includegraphics[width=18.6em]{images/img.png}
    \end{minipage}
   \vspace{0.3em}
}
```

It looks like if I increase the width of the image, it just goes to the right, while there still remains the same little horizontal white space between the left edge of the image and the box.  (I'm using `baposter` here).

I tried `\hspace*{-11em}`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you please post your document code, the output and the `png` file here. That would help people answer.

Comment: If you go `\frame{\includegraphics[width=18.5em]{images/img.png}}` is the unwanted space inside the box or outside it. If it is inside then the white space is part of the image, which ought to be cropped, if it is outside then you have some tex code that you have not shown that is producing the space/

Comment: no, the white space isn't part of the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "before"? To the left (horizontally) or above (vertically)?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I added more details to my question.

Comment: Is the "same horizontal distance" very small? It could be because of a spurious space in your definition of `\headerbox`. End the first line with `%` (see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)). If this still does not solve your problem, consider posting a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) (replacing your `images/img.png` with something like `example-image-a` (from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)). It'll speed up any forthcoming solutions greatly.

Comment: Woah! `%` worked!